# Supermicro IPMI remote console security level to low

Tags: supermicro

I am currently trying to access my supermicro IPMI remote console in my browser but every time I try to open it Java sais that the security setting of the application is to low, it must be high or very high.

I tried to find any Firmware update but it seems like I am up to date, even if my firmware build is from August 2012.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to add an exception for the IP and/or hostname of the IPMI interface into the security tab of your Java control panel on your client. It's slow and painful to manage, but it will work.

Be careful: Java will differentiate between `https` and `http` variants, it doesn't accept wildcards and is a general pain in the rear.

https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml

---

Writing this answer prompted me to look into the exception business a bit closer and it turns out this list is managed in a plain text file named `exception.sites` that is located in your Java preferences (e.g. `~/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/security` on MacOS), which makes it much easier to edit and share this list.

Answer (score 1):

I found something interesting in the Supermicro FAQ.
http://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=17909
There they say that you can download a new Testing Firmware version and it will work but you have to contact the support.

I already tried to add a exception for the application but it either wont work or I have added the wrong URL. Which URL do I have to add ?
I tried to add the one of the interface itself, just without the /index.php, tried to add the URL of the Application itself, but this won´t help either.

Comment: You need to use either the hostname or the IP and the protocol, so e.g. `https://192.168.1.100` or `https://ipmi-server01.example.com`, nothing more.

Comment: This was the first thing i tried but it didn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

All right, it worked with http:// instead of https://
I´m not sure why https:/ won´t work, but thank you for your help

Comment: Small update, check the model of your motherboard, look for a firmware update and install it.
If you can´t find one try to contact the Supermicro support.
After installing the update it should work without disabeling the security.